# RMarkdown cyrillic encoding of leaflet popup

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, r-leaflet

On my windows machine I got this encoding problems. I'm making an interactive map using `leaflet` and `rmarkdown`. The point is, that map title and popup should be in **Russian**. When I'm just creating a `leaflet` object, everything works fine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia")

df <- tibble(X = rnorm(100, 28, 2),
             y = rnorm(100, 42, 4),
             id = seq(1, 100, 1),
             text = c(rep("Валар", 50),
                      rep("Моргулис", 50))) %>% 
  SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = .[, c(1:2)],
                         data = .,
                         proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

popup1 <- paste0("<span style='color: salmon;'><strong>РУССКИЙ ТЕКСТ: </strong></span>", 
                 df$text)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap",
                   options = tileOptions(minZoom=1, maxZoom=14)) %>% 
  leaflet::addMarkers(data = df,
                      popup = popup1)
```

[image]

However, when I'm trying to knit this code to a `html` using `rmarkdown` I get a normal Cyrillic title and empty popup messages:

````
---
title: "Сэмпл текст"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(flexdashboard)

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia")

df <- tibble(X = rnorm(100, 28, 2),
             y = rnorm(100, 42, 4),
             id = seq(1, 100, 1),
             text = c(rep("Валар", 50),
                      rep("Моргулис", 50))) %>% 
  SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = .[, c(1:2)],
                         data = .,
                         proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

popup1 <- paste0("<span style='color: salmon;'><strong>РУССКИЙ ТЕКСТ: </strong></span>", 
                 df$text)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap",
                   options = tileOptions(minZoom=1, maxZoom=14)) %>% 
  leaflet::addMarkers(data = df,
                      popup = popup1)
```
````

[image]

When I'm trying to specify encoding in chunk options `{r setup, echo=FALSE, R.options=options(encoding = "utf-8")}`, everything goes worse:

[image]

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.3-1      leaflet_2.0.2 sf_0.7-3      dplyr_0.8.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0            pillar_1.3.1          compiler_3.5.1       
 [4] later_0.7.5           class_7.3-14          tools_3.5.1          
 [7] digest_0.6.18         evaluate_0.13         jsonlite_1.5         
[10] tibble_2.0.1          lattice_0.20-35       pkgconfig_2.0.2      
[13] rlang_0.3.1           shiny_1.2.0           DBI_1.0.0            
[16] rstudioapi_0.8        crosstalk_1.0.0       yaml_2.2.0           
[19] rgdal_1.3-9           xfun_0.6              e1071_1.7-0          
[22] knitr_1.22            htmlwidgets_1.4       flexdashboard_0.5.1.1
[25] classInt_0.3-1        grid_3.5.1            tidyselect_0.2.5     
[28] glue_1.3.0            R6_2.3.0              rmarkdown_1.12       
[31] purrr_0.3.1           magrittr_1.5          promises_1.0.1       
[34] htmltools_0.3.6       units_0.6-2           rsconnect_0.8.10     
[37] assertthat_0.2.0      mime_0.6              xtable_1.8-3         
[40] httpuv_1.4.5          crayon_1.3.4
```